# set form values by query parameters in zend2 form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

i created a form with zend 2 but i want to use my form in get method

after form submitted
the url is this : zendtst.com/search?price=2

but when page load the default value in my input is empty that i excepted to be 2

my input created like this :

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title" class="control-label col-md-1 pull-right"><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('price')); ?></label>
            <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
               <?php  echo $this->formElement($form->get('price')); ?>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
                <?php echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('price')); ?>
            </div>
```

what should i do to my query params be default of my inputs 
i need to use query params for my search page

Comment: Show us the controller action that processes that form. My bet you haven't actually set the query data on the form object. https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Form.php#L254

Comment: @guessimtoolate thank you my friend i forgot to use setData please post your answer to i accept it thank you so much

Comment: No worries, posted my suggestion as an anwer. Happy "zending"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`setData`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Form.php#L254) on the form object and pass in the query/post data to the form. After that you'll probably want to call [`isValid`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Form.php#L468) on the form as well. That way the form will display the values passed through query params.